# Trying to add an object to a list in a Model via Html Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, forms

I've been trying to add an object to a list in my model, via the HTML form

My Recipe Class:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
    private string _key;

    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            if (_key == null)
            {
                _key = Regex.Replace(Title.ToLower(), "[^a-z0-9]", "-");
            }
            return _key;
        }
        set { _key = value; }
    }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ingredienser")]
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fremgangsmåde")]
    public string Method { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Titel")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
    public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; } = new List<Rating>();
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public Rating NewRating { get; set; } = new Rating();

    public double CalculateRating()
    {
        if (Ratings.Count == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return Ratings.Average(x => x.Value);
    }
```

What i've been trying:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Rating", "Home", FormMethod.Post, Model.Id))
{
<p>

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NewRating)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NewRating.Value, 0)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NewRating.Value, 1)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NewRating.Value, 2)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NewRating.Value, 3)
</p>
<p>
    <button type="submit">Giv Karakter</button>
</p>
}
```

and here's the method i'm posting to:

```
public IActionResult Rating([FromForm] int RecipeId, Rating rating)
        {
            rating.Posted = DateTime.Now;
            var recipe = _db.Recipes.Where(x => x.Id == RecipeId).Include(e => 
            e.Comments).FirstOrDefault();
            recipe.Ratings.Add(rating);
            _db.Update<Recipe>(recipe);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

My problem is that i am not recieving a ratings object in my Rating method as i should, i can't figure out how to directly add an object to a list via a form
(this list is of course empty, since i cant add items to it yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to MVC binder behavior and deserialization, please keep the same instance name, during POST.  So change the following line like below ("Rating NewRating")

```
public IActionResult Rating([FromForm] int RecipeId, Rating NewRating)
```

That should work.